# How to retrieve overall accuracy value from confusionMatrix in R?

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

In R caret library, if I got a confusion matrix like this below, if there a way to retrieve the overall accuracy 0.992? I can't get this single value out, since I need to store this value and use it for later processing. Is this possible at all?

```
 Prediction    A    B    C    D    E
          A 1114    2    0    0    0
          B    9  745    5    0    0
          C    0    6  674    4    0
          D    0    0    3  640    0
          E    0    0    2    1  718
```

Overall Statistics

```
            Accuracy : 0.992         
              95% CI : (0.989, 0.994)
 No Information Rate : 0.286         
 P-Value [Acc > NIR] : <2e-16        

               Kappa : 0.99
```

Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA

Statistics by Class:

```
                     Class: A Class: B Class: C Class: D Class: E
 Sensitivity             0.992    0.989    0.985    0.992    1.000
 Specificity             0.999    0.996    0.997    0.999    0.999
 Pos Pred Value          0.998    0.982    0.985    0.995    0.996
 Neg Pred Value          0.997    0.997    0.997    0.998    1.000
 Prevalence              0.286    0.192    0.174    0.164    0.183
 Detection Rate          0.284    0.190    0.172    0.163    0.183
 Detection Prevalence    0.284    0.193    0.174    0.164    0.184
 Balanced Accuracy       0.996    0.992    0.991    0.996    1.000
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Given a confusion  matrix `cm`, the overall accuracy is obtained by `overall.accuracy <- cm$overall['Accuracy']`

It's the first time I see the `caret` package, so how did I know this?

Since you didn't provide an example, I searched for an [example code for caret confusion matrices](http://www.inside-r.org/node/86995).  Here it is (I only added assignment in the last statement):

```
###################
## 3 class example

confusionMatrix(iris$Species, sample(iris$Species))

newPrior <- c(.05, .8, .15)
names(newPrior) <- levels(iris$Species)

cm <- confusionMatrix(iris$Species, sample(iris$Species))
```

Now, let's take a look what's in the confusion matrix:

```
> str(cm)
List of 5
 $ positive: NULL
 $ table   : 'table' int [1:3, 1:3] 13 18 19 20 13 17 17 19 14
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ Prediction: chr [1:3] "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
  .. ..$ Reference : chr [1:3] "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
 $ overall : Named num [1:7] 0.267 -0.1 0.198 0.345 0.333 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "Accuracy" "Kappa" "AccuracyLower" "AccuracyUpper" ...
 $ byClass : num [1:3, 1:8] 0.26 0.26 0.28 0.63 0.63 0.64 0.26 0.26 0.28 0.63 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Class: setosa" "Class: versicolor" "Class: virginica"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:8] "Sensitivity" "Specificity" "Pos Pred Value" "Neg Pred Value" ...
 $ dots    : list()
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "confusionMatrix"
```

As you may see, the `cm` object is a list. We see various "byClass" and "overall" statistics. The overall part is obtained by:

```
overall <- cm$overall
```

Which gives us a vector of numbers with string indices:

```
> overall
      Accuracy          Kappa  AccuracyLower  AccuracyUpper   AccuracyNull AccuracyPValue  McnemarPValue 
     0.2666667     -0.1000000      0.1978421      0.3449492      0.3333333      0.9674672      0.9547790
```

Now, extracting the relevant value is as simple as:

```
> overall.accuracy <- overall['Accuracy']
```

Summary: `str` is your friend. Another useful function is `attributes` -- it returns all the attributes of a given object.

Comment: Nice answer but accuracy return a string and a value, how can I just access the value? I mean the double

Comment: @Emixam23 you might have figured out by now the solution for your question, but for someone who is looking for answer, just add another square brackets in front and back of the brackets mentioned above, like this `overall.accuracy <- overall[['Accuracy']]`